# Is 1 word 4 bytes or 32 bytes in solidity?

Tags: solidity, bytes

I'm confused about the term `word` in solidity. When I google word, it says `1 word = 2 bytes` but whenever I read `word` mentioned in the context of solidity, it sounds like `1 word = 32 bytes`?

What is a `word` in solidity then? Why does it seem like 1 word in solidity is 32 bytes but only 4 bytes in other places?

Comment: A word in Ethereum (not just Solidity) is 32 bytes, or 256 bits.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks, is `1 word = 32 bytes = 256 bits` something specific to only Ethereum and Solidity? That means, in Solidity, it uses a 256-bit word. But in a different system or VM like Java, it uses 32-bit word. Hence, the term `word` here is different with different systems, is my understanding correct?

Comment: I guess so. I am not familiar with the JVM. You might want to re-articulate your question and post it on the [Software Engineering StackExchange website](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Oh JVM is just a random example here. What I was trying to understand is that different systems will have different number of bytes for a word, right? And in the case of EVM, it just designed such that 1 word is 32 bytes. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know for sure. And this isn't a specific question about Ethereum - that is why I redirected you to the SE StackExchange.

Comment: @xenon - Yes, I'd say the assertion in your final message is correct. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes)

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying my doubts! :)